# Remainder Being negative or positive?

Tags: divisibility

I'm trying to determine if I would have a negative or positive remainder. I'm writing a program that would divide $-326$ by $7$. The program gives me $-46$ with a remainder of $-4$, however when I checked some other results online I got that my remainder would be $3$. I'm just unsure which would be the proper remainder in this case.

Thanks

Comment: $$-46 \cdot 7 + -4 = -326 =  -47 \cdot 7 + 3$$  Typically, we want the remainder $r$ so that $0 \leq r \lt 7$ in this case, (7 because we are dividing my 7, i.e., working in mod 7) hence, we have that $-326 = -47\cdot 7 + 3$.  The quotient is -47, the remainder is 3.

Comment: That's kind of a question of definitions, $-4\equiv 3\pmod 7$, the result of the division is just different.. I would favor a positive remainder.

Comment: The program cannot give you -46 with a remainder of 3.  Please see my comment above.   To get a remainder of $3$, we need the quotient -47 and remainder 3.  As $-326 = -47(7) + 3$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Henrik.  Deleted question, will delete this comment too.

Answer (score 0):

The remainder is $3$. The reainder of the division of an integer $a$ by a natural number $b$ is always an element of $\{0,1,\ldots,b-1\}$.

Comment: Am I able to have a negative remainder?

Comment: @Camilo No, since the set $\{0,1,\ldots,b-1\}$ contains no negative number.

Comment: The remainder isn't 3 if the quotient is  $-46$.  $(-46)(7) = -322 $.  We need quotient $-47$ to have a positive remainder of $3$.  You've not addressed quotient.

Comment: @mr_e_man We're talking about [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) here.